# how to mock login and login error in jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, firebase

This is the code that I need to do the unit test

```
$scope.FBLogin = function () {
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.$authData = authData;
                $scope.isAdmin = true;
            });
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }
    });
};
```

how can I mock the login behavior in jasmine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used Firebase, so I don't know if it provides that, but if it doesn't, extract the call to `new Firebase()` into a service, that you can inject, and that returns a promise. It's then trivial to spy on the service and making it return a fake promise.

Comment: Sorry, can you show me some simple codes how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [AngularFire unit tests](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/tree/master/tests/unit)? They use jasmine.createSpy(), which has a `.and.returnValue( returnValueHere )` you can use to mock results.